# Composer update and mb-string is missing on php5.6 - centos 7

Tags: php, laravel, centos, composer-php

I have laravel project. When I run `composer update`

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - laravel/framework v5.3.9 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.3.8 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.3.7 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.3.6 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.3.5 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.3.4 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.3.3 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.3.26 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.3.25 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.3.24 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.3.23 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.3.22 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.3.21 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.3.20 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.3.2 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.3.19 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.3.18 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.3.17 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.3.16 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.3.15 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.3.14 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.3.13 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.3.12 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.3.11 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.3.10 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.3.1 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.3.0 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.3.23 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for laravel/framework 5.3.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.3.0, v5.3.1, v5.3.10, v5.3.11, v5.3.12, v5.3.13, v5.3.14, v5.3.15, v5.3.16, v5.3.17, v5.3.18, v5.3.19, v5.3.2, v5.3.20, v5.3.21, v5.3.22, v5.3.23, v5.3.24, v5.3.25, v5.3.26, v5.3.3, v5.3.4, v5.3.5, v5.3.6, v5.3.7, v5.3.8, v5.3.9].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in those .ini files:
    - /etc/php.ini
    - /etc/php.d/bz2.ini
    - /etc/php.d/calendar.ini
    - /etc/php.d/ctype.ini
    - /etc/php.d/curl.ini
    - /etc/php.d/exif.ini
    - /etc/php.d/fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php.d/ftp.ini
    - /etc/php.d/gettext.ini
    - /etc/php.d/gmp.ini
    - /etc/php.d/iconv.ini
    - /etc/php.d/json.ini
    - /etc/php.d/opcache.ini
    - /etc/php.d/phar.ini
    - /etc/php.d/shmop.ini
    - /etc/php.d/simplexml.ini
    - /etc/php.d/sockets.ini
    - /etc/php.d/tokenizer.ini
    - /etc/php.d/xml.ini
    - /etc/php.d/zip.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

I have those modules of php:

```
[PHP Modules]
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
ereg
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gettext
gmp
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mhash
openssl
pcntl
pcre
Phar
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
sockets
SPL
standard
tokenizer
xml
Zend OPcache
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
Zend OPcache
```

when I try install mb-strings using this command: sudo yum install php-mbstring than php-common has conflict with php 5.4.

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.mirrors.hoobly.com
 * epel: mirror.sjc02.svwh.net
 * extras: mirror.pac-12.org
 * updates: mirrors.sonic.net
 * webtatic: us-east.repo.webtatic.com
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-mbstring.x86_64 0:5.4.16-36.3.el7_2 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-36.3.el7_2 for package: php-mbstring-5.4.16-36.3.el7_2.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.4.16-36.3.el7_2 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libzip.so.2()(64bit) for package: php-common-5.4.16-36.3.el7_2.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libzip.x86_64 0:0.10.1-8.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Conflict: php56w-common-5.6.28-1.w7.x86_64 conflicts php-common < 5.6
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: php56w-common conflicts with php-common-5.4.16-36.3.el7_2.x86_64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

please help me what can I do to run composer update ad fix this issue.
Thank you.

Comment: what PHP version are you working with? Do you have the option to change the PHP version?

Comment: I have VPS on Godaddy. I can change php version.
but now I use only php 5.6 version

php -v
PHP 5.6.28 (cli) (built: Nov 10 2016 20:36:59)
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies

Comment: Well, just add it to your php.ini file. it should work.

Comment: how can add in php.ini? plz show me example

Comment: You clearly have the php56w package installed, not php.  So try installing php56w-mbstring not php-mbstring.  CentOS doesn't support PHP 5.6, you're using a third party package from Webtatic.com